# how to get value from input and have AJAX produce response

Tags: php, ajax

I want the user to enter a value in a text field.  Then based on what is typed into the text field, a request is made to a php file that will produce a breif description of that specific state that was typed in.

Here is what i have.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    function getData(dataSource, divID)
    {
        if (XMLHttpRequestObject)
        {
            var obj = document.getElementById(divID);
            obj.innerHTML = "";
            XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataSource);
            XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = 
                function()
                {
                    if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200)
                    {
                        obj.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
                    }
                }
                XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
        }
    }
    </script>

<form>
        <p>Enter State:</p>
        <input type="text" name="State">
        <br>
        <br>

      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="getData('k5a.php?state=2', 'targetDiv')">
</form>

<div id="targetDiv">
    <p>The state Info will appear here.</p>

    </div
```

So the php file looks like

```
<?php
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=1, pre-check=2");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    $choice = $_GET['state'];



    switch ($choice)
    {
            case 1:
                echo "California is the most populous state in the United States and the third most extensive by area. Located on the western (Pacific Ocean) coast of the U.S., California is bordered by the other U.S. states of Oregon, Nevada, and Arizona and shares an international border with the Mexican state of Baja California.";
                break;

            case 2:
                echo "Florida is a state located in the southeastern region of the United States. It is bordered to the west by the Gulf of Mexico, to the north by Alabama and Georgia, to the east by the Atlantic Ocean, and to the south by the Straits of Florida and Cuba. Florida is the 22nd most extensive, the 3rd most populous, and the 8th most densely populated of the U.S. states.";
                break;

            case 3:
                echo "New York is the most populous city in the United States. With an estimated 2015 population of 8,550,405 distributed over a land area of about 302.6 square miles. New York City is also the most densely populated major city in the United States. Located at the southern tip of the state of New York, the city is the center of the New York metropolitan area, one of the most populous urban agglomerations in the world.";
                break;

    }
    ?>
```

I want the output to be info on whatever state the user enters.  I'm stuck on how to do the switch statement/onclick method.

Comment: could you describe what exactly is not working?

Comment: @shofstetter how to get the input value to correspound with switch statement...ie enter California, california's info will display

Comment: Instead of `case 1:` put `case "California":` and so on and so forth

Comment: @eeetee can you do New York? with a space?

Comment: Yes. One problem I already see you might have is that people will type things out differently. The switch function is case-sensitive so **California** is different from **california**. You can make what they type, lowercase, and have the cases in lowercase: `switch (strtolower($choice)) {` which will make **CaLiFoRniA** or however the user inputs it into **california** have the case as `case "california":` so they'll always match.

Comment: @eeetee Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new javascript function `sendData()` which gets triggered by the onclick event of the submit button:

```
<script>
...
function sendData(){
    getData('k5.php?state='+document.getElementById("state_input").value, 'targetDiv');
}
</script>
```

This function reads the value of the input element and calls your getData() function.

You also need to give your input element an id:

```
<input type="text" name="State" id="state_input">
```

Then you need to call that new function when the submit button gets clicked:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="sendData();">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use a `select` list to ensure users choose a valid option.

```
<p>Select State:</p>
<select id="states">
    <option value="1">California</option>
    <option value="2">Florida</option>
    <option value="3">New York</option>
</select>
```

Then to keep your `getData` function flexible for other uses, pass the selected option as a third parameter instead of a hard-coded query string URL.

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="getData('k5a.php?state=', 'targetDiv', 'states')">
```

In your function grab the selected value like this:

```
var select = document.getElementById(selector);
var state = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
```

Lastly append your URL query string with the ID

```
XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataSource + state);
```

Putting it all together:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }


    // declare extra selector parameter
    function getData(dataSource, divID, selector)
    {
        if (XMLHttpRequestObject)
        {

            // get selected option
            var select = document.getElementById(selector);
            var state = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

            var obj = document.getElementById(divID);
            obj.innerHTML = "";

            // append URL query string
            XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataSource + state);
            XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = 
                function()
                {
                    if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200)
                    {
                        obj.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
                    }
                }
                XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
        }
    }
</script>
<body>
<form>

    <!-- use a select list -->
    <p>Select State:</p>
    <select id="states">
        <option value="1">California</option>
        <option value="2">Florida</option>
        <option value="3">New York</option>
    </select>

        <br>
        <br>

    <!-- pass that value into function -->
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="getData('k5a.php?state=', 'targetDiv', 'states')">
</form>

<div id="targetDiv">
    <p>The state Info will appear here.</p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```